# How to connect another node to my own private network?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, private-blockchain

i have followed [this](https://codeburst.io/build-your-first-ethereum-smart-contract-with-solidity-tutorial-94171d6b1c4b) guide and set up my own private blockchain. Now the only node that mines and sets smart contracts is my own computer, but I want to connect another computer to my network. How do I do that? And not just for mining, but to be seen in Mist, too (to participate in smart contracts).

Also a "bonus" simple question - the guide says to download the entire Ethereum blockchain and then set up a private network, but i don't understand why download the entire blockchain, when youre in the end setting up your private network anyway? Isn't the guide wrong?

Comment: just modify `params/bootnodes.go` to add your bootnode, then run `bootnode` binary, now distribute your `geth` binary and everybody will connect to your network automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By another computer, I'm assuming you mean a separate machine within your the same LAN? Did you assign it a unique IP or is just on a subnet?

Either way, try `admin.addPeer("enode://address@ip:port")`in console.

Another option is to set up a `static-peers.json` file. I answered a similar question a couple days ago you can refer to for more details.

I didn't read the guide you posted, but you definitely don't need to download the Ethereum main net in order to launch your own private network. You just need to init a customgenesis.json that specifies the networkid and then get to work. Be sure to indicate `--networkid` when launching your geth instance.

Comment: Thank you! I have seen other people saying to indicate --networkid when launching, but I went by the guide, and it didn't specify that. I do have **"chainId": 15** in the genesis.json file, though. Could that be it? And if I didn't indicate it, should I start from scratch? And what is the "address" part in the command you mentioned?

Comment: `ChainID` and `networkid` are the same thing. I'd choose something longer than 15 unless you're ok with other nodes who have the same genesis file potentially syncing with your testnet.

Comment: Example: 
`"enode://82bf100dc69d83e49741fd6fd727c51513bc24b2340d12c285ebab1cbdfb6c9a92d78bc4738e89733cebcf5477046081f1ec8aeb2e8250f6b6241f8b79a7e27e@[::]:30303"`

When indicating a peer, add this enode address, but be sure to replace `[::]` with that particular node's IP address and specify the port if it's different than the default port number.

Example:
`"enode://82bf100dc69d83e49741fd6fd727c51513bc24b2340d12c285ebab1cbdfb6c9a92d78bc4738e58963cebcf5477046081f1ec8aeb2e8250f6b6241f8b79a7e27e@10.10.101.5:30303"`

Comment: enode address is similar to a mac address. You can find it in console with `admin.nodeInfo.enode`